# R gmm package using exactly identified moment conditions

Tags: r

For exactly identified moments, GMM results should be the same regardless of initial starting values. This doesn't appear to be the case however.

```
library(gmm)
data(Finance)
x <- data.frame(rm=Finance[1:500,"rm"], rf=Finance[1:500,"rf"])

# want to solve for coefficients theta[1], theta[2] in exactly identified         
    # system
g <- function(theta, x)
{
  m.1 <- x[,"rm"] - theta[1] - theta[2]*x[,"rf"]
  m.z <- (x[,"rm"] - theta[1] - theta[2]*x[,"rf"])*x[,"rf"]
  f <- cbind(m.1, m.z)
  return(f)
}

# gmm coefficient result should be identical to ols regressing rm on rf     
  # since two moments are E[u]=0 and E[u*rf]=0
model.lm <- lm(rm ~ rf, data=x)
model.lm 

# gmm is consistent with lm given correct starting values
summary(gmm(g, x, t0=model.lm$coefficients))

# problem is that using different starting values leads to different
  # coefficients
summary(gmm(g, x, t0=rep(0,2)))
```

Is there something wrong with my setup?

Comment: You could profile likelihood and see the 'landscape'. If there are local minima, I would not be surprised if solutions differ depending on the starting values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gmm package author Pierre Chausse was kind enough to respond to my inquiry.

For linear models, he suggests using the formula approach:

```
gmm(rm ~ rf, ~rf, data=x)
```

For non-linear models, he emphasizes that the starting values are indeed critical. In the case of exactly identified models, he suggests setting the fnscale to a small number to force the optim minimizer to converge closer to 0. Also, he thinks the BFGS algorithm works better with GMM.

```
summary(gmm(g, x, t0=rep(0,2), method = "BFGS", control=list(fnscale=1e-8)))
```

Both solutions work for this example. Thanks Pierre!